# How can I force TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS error?

Tags: javascript, redirect, react-router, react-router-dom

I need to create a page that forces a TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS error... just to test a script.

Does anyone know how I could replicate/simulate this error?

Comment: Did you try creating 2 routes that redirect to each other? Or a single route that redirects to itself?

Comment: yes =/  https://redir1.netlify.app/